# Poll server with a timer in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am in a spot where I need to poll my server for data every so often.  I have looked around at how people are handling this in angularjs and I am pretty confused.

Some examples are of just simple counters that increment up/down.  Other are using the $timeout service.  I need the ability to turn this on/off with a button click.  I.E. click to start poll, poll every 30 seconds, click button to stop polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not claiming to be great at javascript nor angular so please go easy.  I did write my own service that uses setInterval and clearInterval:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('TimerService',
    function () {
      var timers = {};

      var startTimer = function(name, interval, callback) {
        // Stop the timer if its already running, no-op if not running
        stopTimer(name);

        timers[name] = setInterval(function() {
          callback();
        }, interval);

        // Fire right away, interval will fire again in specified interval
        callback();
      }


      var stopTimer = function(name) {
        var timer = timers[name];
        if (timer) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          delete timers[name];
        }
      }

      return {
        start: startTimer,
        stop: stopTimer
      };
    });
```

Then in my controller I do this:

```
  var timerARunning = false;
  $scope.onClickA = function() {
    var timerName = 'timerA';
    timerARunning = !timerARunning;

    if (timerARunning) {
      TimerService.start(timerName, 5000, function() {
         alert("Timer A just fired");
      });
    } else {
      TimerService.stop(timerName);
    }
  }
```